# Remove d3 tooltip onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am using d3 charts to show a scatter plot. I am showing tooltip on click. I have to remove the tooltip if I click anywhere on the page. How should I remove the tooltip?

```
var svg = d3.select("#scatter_plot")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", chart_width)
  .attr("height", chart_height)
// create x_scale

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip1 scatter_tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);
// add circles
svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function (d) {
    return x_scale(d.Staff_count)
  })
  .attr("cy", function (d) {
    return y_scale(d.Outlets)
  })
  .attr("r", function (d) {
    return a_scale(d.Total_Sales)
  })
  .attr("fill", function (d) { return scatter_color(d.Total_Sales) })
  .on("click", function (d) {
    var div_html = "<div class='d-flex justify-content-center m-2'><div class='font-weight-bolder pr-2'>"
    var div_end =  "<hr>" + "</div></div>" + div_html + "Total Sales" + ": " + d.Total_Sales + "</div></div>" + "</div></div>"+ div_html + "Outlets" + ": " + d.Outlets + "</div></div>" + "</div></div>"+ div_html + "Staff Count" + ": " + d.Staff_count
    $(".tooltip1").show()
    div.transition()
      .duration(100)
      .style("opacity", .9);
    if (state_ == 'India') {
      div.html(div_html + d.State + div_end + "</div></div>" + "<button class = 'myBtn btn btn-primary' id='" + d.State + "'>District Details >></button>")
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
    } else {
      div.html(div_html + d.District + div_end)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
    }
    tooltip_load()
    toolTipIsVisible()
  })
```

It would be helpful if anyone gives some idea of how to work this out.

Comment: you can listen to the click event on the document and hide the tooltip in its handler, but don't forget to call stopPropagation() in svg circle's click event handler.

Comment: Will this work as I'm appending the tooltip to the body? @Spark.Bao

Comment: let me have a look.

Comment: I paste the example code, please have a try. @SPL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the click event on the body or document as the global click event handler, in this handler, you can hide the tooltip. Inside the circle click event handler, you need to stop the click event propagate to the body or document by calling `d3.event.stopPropagation()`。

Example code:

```
  .attr("fill", function (d) { return scatter_color(d.Total_Sales) })
  .on("click", function (d) {
    var div_html = "<div class='d-flex justify-content-center m-2'><div class='font-weight-bolder pr-2'>"
    var div_end =  "<hr>" + "</div></div>" + div_html + "Total Sales" + ": " + d.Total_Sales + "</div></div>" + "</div></div>"+ div_html + "Outlets" + ": " + d.Outlets + "</div></div>" + "</div></div>"+ div_html + "Staff Count" + ": " + d.Staff_count
    $(".tooltip1").show()
    div.transition()
      .duration(100)
      .style("opacity", .9);
    if (state_ == 'India') {
      div.html(div_html + d.State + div_end + "</div></div>" + "<button class = 'myBtn btn btn-primary' id='" + d.State + "'>District Details >></button>")
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
    } else {
      div.html(div_html + d.District + div_end)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
    }
    tooltip_load()
    toolTipIsVisible()

    // added code
    d3.event.stopPropagation()
  })

  // global listener
  d3.select('body').on('click', resetTooltip)

  function resetTooltip() {
    // reset tooltip state
    div.style('opacity', 0)
    $(".tooltip1").hide()
  }
```

There is an example here: http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/3186840

Comment: So here we are not hiding the tooltip here right? We are just changing the opacity it is not working when I again click on the tooltip. @Spark.Bao

Comment: ok, I add the `$(".tooltip1").hide()` under the `div.style('opacity', 0)`, but I don't know how `tooltip_load()` and `toolTipIsVisible()` work, maybe I can write a demo in codepen. @SPL

Comment: see this demo code: https://codepen.io/baurine/pen/XWWmJNr?editors=1111  @SPL

Answer (score 0):

Once you come out of the component and just before the new tooltip is to be created, you can use:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.d3-tip'), (t) => t.parentNode.removeChild(t));
```

Comment: Can you include inline code span so the code is readable & verifiable.